# Normalizing small data column that sometimes may be a list

Tags: sql

I'm still in the beginning steps of teaching myself database design on the job and I really want to make sure I do this right.  I have this table of doctors, one column of which is their titles ("DDS","MD","DMD", etc).  I was thinking since there are thousands of doctors, but maybe only a dozen titles, it might make sense to make a separate table just for the titles, even though the titles aren't very big.  Does it make sense?  To throw another wrench into the thought process, there are a couple doctors with multiple titles.  If I did make a separate "titles" table, would I just put in something like "4,7,9" under the titleID column in the doctors table?  I don't think that would work with foreign key references.  Is there a "right" way of handing this?   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You would have a many to many table relationship between Doctors and Titles.

Something like

```
tblDoctors
- DoctorID (PK)
- LastName
- FirstName
```

and then

```
tblTitles
- TitleID (PK)
- TitleDesc
```

and then

```
tblDoctorTitles
- DoctorID (PK,FK)
- TitleID (PK,FK)
```

When you store it as mentioned (in a single column) you will always have issues later when you wish to query/join these fields, so it would be best to design it correct from the start.

Comment: That seems pretty complex.  Is it really worth the extra effort?  The only thing that the titles will currently be used for is to append to doctor names when outputted.  For all planned uses, the titles could actually just be appended to each doctor and saved in the "name" column.  I definitely can imaginine other cases where creating a many-to-many table like you suggested is the best idea, I'm just trying to sell myself on the idea that it's worth all the extra work to build the database like that and have more complex queries to get the title every time I want to output the doctor name.

Comment: You indicated in your question that "I really want to make sure I do this right". The above is the right way. Rather learn database normalization and apply it from day one. It will make development easier and you will rarely have to modify current structure of the tables. This provides manageability as well as scalability. Start small the right way so you are ready when it becomes big.

Comment: @ConradLotz - ok, thanks.  So the official "right" way is to make separate tables for any column that can have repeated data, even if it makes it more complex and there's no foreseeable benefit for it?  I just wasn't sure where the line (if any) should be drawn for being worth it to make a separate table.  I was just thinking this would be an easy first project, my client gave me a simple 10-column spreadsheet that's easily converted into an SQL table.  And now normalization looks like it will make it a 20-table (about 60 columns in all) database.  Normalization makes it so much more complex!